# How do I combine vue, i18n and markdown pages?

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vue-i18n

I’m trying to use markdown pages as translations in vue.

This is my attempt to get it working:

*Home.vue*

```
<template>
  <div v-html="$t('page')">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Page from '@/components/BonjourLeMonde.md'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Page
  }
}
</script>

<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "page": "<h1>Welcome to my homepage!</h1><br>Doesn't this look awesome?"
  },
  "fr": {
    "page": "Non? <Page />"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

*BonjourLeMonde.md*

```
# Bonjour tout le monde!

Bienvenue pour mon site de web.
```

Unfortunately, while html tags can be read, imports are not being loaded.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

[Link to example code](https://gitlab.com/baz-yropeehn/ehgzaqpl/hello-vue-i18n-markdown).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `v-html` with Vue component. From the document [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html):

> Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates. If you find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink the solution by using components instead.

However you can still achieve this by using [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Built-In-Components) and [compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) function.

```html
Render.vue

<template>
  <component :is="result"/>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default {
    props: {
      html: String
    },

    computed: {
      result () {
        return Vue.compile(this.html)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then use it instead of v-html:

```html
<Render :html="$t('page')"/>
```

Register your components as global components (If you want to register locally you can pass your components into Render and register it with the result of compile function):

```js
Vue.component('Post', Post)
```

Note: `Vue.compile` only available in the full build you have to add `runtimeCompiler: true` in `vue.config.js`.

Comment: I wish I could double thank you, because you did help me find the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by using VueSimpleInlineTranslation.

*Home.md*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <translate :current-language="$i18n.locale" language="en"><PageEN /></translate>
    <translate :current-language="$i18n.locale" language="fr"><PageFR /></translate>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueSimpleInlineTranslation } from '@alidrus/vue-simple-inline-translation'
import PageEN from '@/components/HelloWorld.md'
import PageFR from '@/components/BonjourLeMonde.md'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    translate: VueSimpleInlineTranslation,
    PageEN,
    PageFR
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder what's the advantage of this package compared to v-if? I look into the source code but not much understand. Thanks.